# Hyperledger composer CLI installation issues on Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-ec2, hyperledger-composer

I installed composer on AWS ubuntu instance with this command:
`npm i -g @composer-cli@0.19`

On running this command for checking the installation: `composer --help`

I got this error
`composer command not found`

Answer (score 0):

What version of `npm` are you using? Composer only officially supports `npm v5.x` and `node v8.9.x`. In particular, make sure you are not running `npm v6` or any higher versions of node, eg `node v9` or `node v10`.

Comment: I'm using `npm 6.4.1` on the local and is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you see [this Link](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html) for the installation of the development environment  the command for composer installation is:

> npm install -g composer-cli@0.19

but you are using

> npm i -g @composer-cli@0.19

follow the instructions provided in above link, it will work perfectly fine.